# Dask - Kubernetes - Tutorial example

Tags: dataframe, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dask, dask-distributed

I have just finished the setup for Dask on a Kubernetes cluster using Helm and now that I want to do the basic tutorials on the jupyter notebook, I run into the following error:

[image: error-dask]

Also I have tried in another notebook to analyze a 40 GB dataset but it's very slow to run the following commands (I am just importing 40GB from GCS and then making a value_counts on a binary column):

```
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='tme-chrome')

fs.ls('tme-churning')

df = dd.read_csv('gs://tme-churning/*.csv')


df['churning'].value_counts().compute()
```

Thanks a lot for your help. I seem to be missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue using the dask helm chart found [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/dask) and wasn't able to. These are the steps I took:

```
1. helm install -n stable-dask stable/dask
2. Go to output Jupyter IP:PORT
3. Run the first few cells in the notebook.
```

Are you using a different helm chart?